# Button on another .js file not working

Tags: javascript, android, button, titanium, eventhandler

http://pastebin.com/abt2J0Sn

The button on my home screen (app.js) are working fine and when hovered over they change look then when im on another .js file (settings.js) the button don't fire simple events and they don't change look when hovered over.

On mid semester break so cant go and ask teacher.

Comment: you have a Titanium course in your school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

My instructor finally emailed me back and said to use a tab group and now the buttons are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is app.js is loaded only once at app launch so you should not call and open it again rather you can use [NavigationWindow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow) concept to back and forth to windows.

Comment: I replaced it with Navigation but it seems to be still unresponsive  by pressing on it. Even with the alert.

Comment: yes, i saw that but as you said that you replaced it with Navigation so i want to see that updated cod because this is not a proper way to open app.js file again as it should be executed only once.

Comment: I've change from createWindow to 

`function openhome() {
 settingshome.openWindow(home);`

Comment: I still am confused on why the button on the setting.js file won't actually fire an event like alert.

Comment: i still say that its not recomnded to open app.js by createWindow method so just share app.js code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cuVHiewU app.js Sorry about this im not good with this website.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your settings.js file is properly linked to the html. Also try and check the source and resource tabs of your developer tool to confirm if the settings.js file is part of your resources.

Comment: app.js and settings.js are both in the resources folder

Answer (score 0):

You have done something wrong here. You have a local variable called back that holds the reference to your button object, and you also have a function named back.

try using naming conventions for objects and functions like this:

```
var btnBack = Ti.UI.createButton({
    top : '50',
    left : '50',
    width : '50',
    height : '50',
    image : 'images/back.png',
    id : "back button",
});

btnBack.addEventListener('click', back);
```

Comment: The button still is unusable on the settings.js file

Comment: if you put an alert inside the back function (first line of execution in the file) does it shows up?

Comment: No, neither the changecolor function.

Comment: could you try adding btnback after you add the title?